# Open external app intent in full screen?

Tags: android, youtube

From my app, I can open YouTube app like this

```
        PackageManager pm = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube.tv");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

This works fine (opens youtube app), but there are actionbar and topbar present. I need to open this youtube app from my app in full screen mode (nothing visible besides youtube app). Is it possible to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to open this youtube app from my app in full screen mode (nothing visible besides youtube app).

**AFAIK** It is not possible

> Is it possible to do this programatically?

Simple answer **NOT** possible **You can not control other app from your app**

For more information read [**`Interacting with Other Apps`**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open other application by such kind of configuration.